# Undefine a variable in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

How can I set a variable again to being undefined, after giving it a value?

For checking I use the Underscore-function `_.isUndefined()`.

Already tried `myVariable = undefined` and `delete myVariable`

Comment: Why doesn't `myVariable = undefined` work? That is how you set a variable to undefined...

Comment: What version on TypeScript is this? 1.x or 2.x?

Answer (score 3):

Look in the underscope implementation: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1337

Try `myVariable = void 0;`

Comment: The function in underscore has moved to line 1370: https://github.com/jashkenas/underscore/blob/master/underscore.js#L1370